# Start an HTML video to a specified time

Tags: html5-video

I'm building a prototype of a video player that uses HTML Video. My project is in typescript React but that's not really relevant its more about events fired from the HTML Video element.

I'm trying to code it so the video loads and starts from a specific position (eg + 10 seconds) and the Frame displayed in the not-yet-playing video reflects 10 seconds in.

My question is about how the events are fired. I set up the following event listeners to output to the console so I can see what's going on. `loadedMetadata`, `loadedData`, `canplay` and `canplaythrough`.  I expect those events to be fired in that order. Whether I load my mp4 video via an http request or a locally stored file only the metadataload event is triggered. However if I have a callback on the  metadata load event that triggers `videoElement.currentTime = 10` then the other events are fired.

The thing is, when I then play the video the currentTime has not changed (despite `videoElement.currentTime = 10` being called in the `loadedMetadata` callback), the video still plays from the start (0 secs) and the frame displayed confirms that too (it is the first frame of the video).
I've worked out if I put `videoElement.currentTime = 10` in the `loadedmetadata` callback to trigger the other events, and then put another `videoElement.currentTime = 10` in any of the other event callbacks, then it does update the start time and the frame updates to reflect this.
Has anyone got an idea why is this happening and what is the best way to achieve my desired result ?

I'm copying in the code below for a bit more clarity.

```
export function useVideoReadyState() {
    const [videoElement] = useVideoElement()
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (videoElement) {
            videoElement.addEventListener(
                "loadedmetadata",
                handleLoadedMetaData
            )
            videoElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", handleLoadedData)
            videoElement.addEventListener("canplay", handleCanPlay)
            videoElement.addEventListener(
                "canplaythrough",
                handleCanPlayThrough
            )
        }

        function handleLoadedMetaData(event) {
            console.log("loadedmetadata event received")
            videoElement.currentTime = 10
        }
        function handleLoadedData(event) {
            console.log("loaded data event received")
            videoElement.currentTime = 10
        }
        function handleCanPlay(event) {
            console.log("canPlay event received")
        }
        function handleCanPlayThrough(event) {
            console.log("canPlayThrough event received")
        }

        return () => {
            if (videoElement) {
                videoElement.removeEventListener(
                    "loadedmetadata",
                    handleLoadedMetaData
                )
                videoElement.removeEventListener("loadeddata", handleLoadedData)
                videoElement.removeEventListener("canplay", handleCanPlay)
                videoElement.removeEventListener(
                    "canplaythrough",
                    handleCanPlayThrough
                )
            }
        }
    }, [videoElement])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call the t=10 when playback has started - the play()  callback.

Alternatively, html5 allows you to set a starting (and ending time) by adding "#t=," to the url. In your example you want to start a t=10, so your url could look like:

```
https://example.com/myvideo.mp4#t=10
```

reference: https://web.dev/video-and-source-tags/#specify-start-and-end-times